# Bash script to delete a file in all sub directories.

Tags: linux, bash, directory

I have a directory that is filled with subdirectories exceeding 450 GBs.  Inside of these subdirectories is an instruction file in each subdirectory.  I have a script that copies the instruction file in the directory I am currently in and puts it inside every subdirectory via:

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in */; do cp "INSTALLATION INSTRUCTIONS.rtf" "$d"; done
```

I need to remove all of these files in the subdirectories  and replace them with new instructions. Can I simple write another script that does this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in */; do rm "INSTALLATION INSTRUCTIONS.rtf" "$d"; done
```

I am very hesitant and wanted to make sue as these files are vitally important and I don't want to accidentally remove anything and making a backup of 450+ GBs is very taxing.

Comment: The two are quite not like each the other. `cp src target` copies `src` to `target`, whereas `rm arg1 arg2` deletes both `arg1` and `arg2`.

Comment: BTW, why are you removing them as a separate step, vs just overwriting the file in-place?

Comment: Lol see I am so glad I asked.  That would have been horrible to delete both the file and the directory.  How can I simply remove the file inside of all the directories?

Comment: (...now, to be fair, by default `rm` won't delete a directory without being passed `-r`, so unless you had an alias or such adding that, you *probably* wouldn't have had a major data loss event).

Comment: If I run my first script will it replace the file or will it add another one ?  I don't want there to be two instruction files inside of my sub directories.

Comment: You can't have two files with the same name in the same directory, so copying a file with a name that already exists will replace the prior file.

Comment: awesome thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -mindepth 2 -name "INSTALLATION INSTRUCTIONS.rtf" -exec rm -f '{}' +
```

Comment: **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593) (But IMHO, this answer is simple enough that it doesn't need much/any explanation, so it doesn't warrant even a downvote.)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is "vitally important" data, I would first list all files that match the file name you want to delete/overwrite, without taking any action on it (other than listing):

```
find /folder/ -type f -name "INSTALLATION INSTRUCTIONS.rtf" -print > /tmp/holder
```

That would create a list of matches on /tmp/holder. Then you could analyze this list before taking any action (either visually or programatically) to make sure that the list does not include anything you don't want to delete (when dealing with big amounts of data, strange things can happen, so be proactive on protecting the data).

If you are happy with what the list shows, then you could delete the old instructions, or if possible, overwrite them with the new file. Here's an example to overwrite the old file with the new one:

```
while read -r line; do cp --no-preserve=all /folder/newfile "$line"; done < /tmp/holder
```

The `cp --no-preserve=all` command (available on GNU bash) would ensure that the new file has permissions that are "adequate" to the folder where they are located. You may change that to a simple `cp` if you don't want that to happen.

Comment: If it's "vitally important" enough to write to disk for review, it's vitally important enough to use a NUL-delimited rather than newline-delimited stream of names. You wouldn't want a file named `/folder/$'\n'/etc/passwd$'\n'/INSTALLATION\ INSTRUCTIONS.rtf` to trigger deletion of `/etc/passwd`, after all.

Comment: Good point. But that could be (and should be) programmatically checked for on the /tmp/holder file, and prevented entirely. One could also use the temporary file as a "dry run" that allows easy visualization and safe programmatic probing, and then when happy with results just pipe the first line of code on the second (needs adjustments, of course) and that problem can be avoided.

Comment: I disagree about the "should" (though being a security wonk staunchly opposed to the purported moral of [xkcd #327](https://xkcd.com/327/) makes me admittedly an oddity). Why use a mechanism that's prone to a bug, and scan for content that would trigger said bug, as opposed to using  a mechanism that isn't prone to said bug at all? The latter is simpler, has fewer things to go wrong, and avoids putting unnecessary constraints on data being processed.

Comment: Keeping data and code out-of-band from each other, and ensuring that data is stored in a format with constraints that precisely match its domain (which is exactly what is accomplished by using NUL-delimited streams for processing lists of filenames) are part and parcel of the same thing.

Comment: ...similarly, since the domain of content that can be passed as arguments on an argv command line and the domain of filenames is exactly the same, the approach given by my own answer similarly avoids impedance-mismatch issues. (If `find .` weren't guaranteed to prefix answers with `./`, we'd need a `--` after the `-f` and before the `{}`; perhaps I should add that for additional robustness).

Comment: I like the list creation because it allows an easy visualization -- sometimes you don't know what you are looking for until you see it; That is the reason I would still create the list. That being said, you're entirely correct that the best approach would be a null delimiter or to just pipe one command into the other (with adjustments, of course).

Comment: If you want to take a NUL-delimited list and make a version formatted for human review (with nonprintable characters rendered in readable form, each file guaranteed to be rendered onto one line, etc), `while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do printf '%q\n' "$filename"; done` might be an approach to consider.

Comment: Cool, I will keep this construction in mind. Charles, I appreciated your comments and suggestions on this thread, they were spot on and I learned with it. Thanks!